# Javascript - Check which input element cursor is in

Tags: javascript

If I click a random button, is there any way to define in which input element my cursor is currently in?

Comment: So you want to know which element was focused `before` you clicked the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on a button, the cursor will no longer be in the input element.

However you could do something like:

```
<input onFocus="activeInput = this;" />
```

Then when you click the button find the value of `activeInput` and you have your selected input element.